# How to integrate rinkeby test network with centralised server?

Tags: rinkeby, web3.py, web3-providers, aws, ipc

I am new to ethereum blockchain. I want to create ICO platform based website. I have created smart contract and deployed on rinkeby test network. I used python web3.py library to integrate python with solidity.

I am using python django web framework as frontend. I created a instance of solidity compile file in python. And use this instance to retrieve smart contract data. And shows these data on template. It all functionality done with **ganache** local blockchain.

When I deployed smart contract on rinkeby test network. So I change my **web3 HTTP** provider to **IPC provider** in python file.

So In that case I deploy Django functionality on **AWS server**. I find error with IPC provider. Because **geth.ipc**
file missing on server.

So I have Query regarding it:-

**Query 1:-**
How to give **geth** **web3** **IPC** provider in python file when I deployed on **AWS server**??

Thanks.

Comment: Please reduce this to a single core question. (You can ask separate questions in a different post)

Comment: Hi Carver, I updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

If your ethereum node is running on a different VM from your web3 service (Django in this case), then you cannot use IPC. IPC is only available over the local file system.

Check out the [WebsocketProvider](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#websocketprovider) or [HTTPProvider](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#httpprovider), instead. Both of them can connect over a network.

Be security-conscious! Any time your node is available over a network, there is a risk that someone can access your funds, or DoS your node

Comment: Thanks Carver for answering. So is there any solution how I increase my security of fund.

Comment: I highly recommend hiring a security expert.

Comment: Hi Carver.. Which url give in HttpProvider when I connect geth ethereum node with rinkeby test network.